# Css Dropdown menu having difficulties

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website where im having problems with the dropdown menu. When i put my mouse over the menu, it wont show the child nav.
[image: I put my mouse over the fragrance sets]
This is my main_nav codes:

```
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#main_navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  text-align:center;
  margin: auto;
}

#main_navigation li {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: 'Crimson Text'
  font-weight: normal;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#main_navigation li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And this is my dropdown:

```
.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

and this is the HTML: (this website make it easier by using label instead of typing all the list out myself)

```
<div id="main_navigation" class="column">
  <ul>
    {{#navigation}}
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="{{#is_current}}selected{{/is_current}} dropbtn">
        <a href="{{url}}">
          {{label}}
        </a>
      </button>
      {{#is_current}}
      {{! Render the submenu if it has any navigation items }}
      {{#children?}}
      <div class="child_navigation dropdown-content">
        {{#children}}
        <a href="{{url}}">
          {{label}}
        </a>
        {{/children}}
      </div>
      {{/children?}}
      {{/is_current}}
    </div>
{{/navigation}}
```

Still a newbie here>< but i keep trying and still couldn't do it.Please help!

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: how am i gonna share that?o.o

Comment: You go to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and add all releavent code then click on the 'Save' and share the link here or on your question

Comment: A link to the website would be helpful as well.

Comment: Whenever I've mentioned [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) I've made it into a hyperlink, simply click on it --> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) <--

Comment: @TimMarshall https://jsfiddle.net/agafrm3w/ (by the way the label is because the web helps make it easier for myself as i add the product in it will auto make one parent/child)

Comment: @darrylyeo the link is http://cladine.com/ but i did not make changes to the website yet as i could not solve the navigation bar to have the dropdown function

Comment: I see. It's hard to visualize the problem in the JSFiddle since you've abbreviated it so much. Could you provide more context?

Comment: @darrylyeo i could give more codes  in the JSFiddle if is not complicated for u>< the website i share is originally like this but i wanted to try to make it become a horizontal dropdown menu as i think is much better than put it at the side there.

Comment: By all means. Nothing is too complicated for the StackOverflow community.

Comment: @darrylyeo i have updated the JSFiddle you can have a look! sorry for troubling you guys><

Comment: I am using a web called tictail.com to set up this website as it is easier for me to add navigation when i add my products.
http://imgur.com/TO4XJh0

Comment: @darryleo opps this is the updated one! https://jsfiddle.net/agafrm3w/5/

Comment: It would help to see the end result, after all the labels have been replaced.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you cannot gain help via a JSFiddle which does not display like it does on your website otherwise we could give the wrong advice.